# The getter title isnt defined for the type "TextTheme"

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgraded to flutter v2. I am getting the following error

```
title: Text("Foo", style: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .title
                            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),)),
```

Any suggestions on what the equivalent will be ?

Answer (score 3):

In 2018 many text styles were renamed. The “title” style is now called “headline6”.

You can read more about migrating here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html